# Next.js poor performance (request/second) for large page

Tags: performance, next.js, next.js13, bottleneck

My goal is to move specifc service from older technology  (Java + tomcat + jsp) to next.js.

Requirements:

- Page must be generated as SSR (every user sees different data)
- Page is large (over 800kB, over 2000 DOM elements)
- I cannot use lazy loading - all content must be served at once (required by SEO dep.)

I have an app using Next.js 13.5.5, node 18.16.1.

Page generation looks like this:

- I call one backend endpoint (just for tests it returns static data - response time < 30ms)
- Based on this data I generate ~2000 divs (each one has image <img> and title <p> below
- THATS ALL WHAT I HAVE IN MY CODE

I use fasthttploader to benchmark my app.

When I run it with 10 clients and 10 requests per second the result I get is very weak (~1,5 - 2 sec).

[image: nextjs 10 req/sec]

The same paged servered on tomcat - for 30 req/sec (3 TIMES MORE !) the result I get is very good (~ 0,10 - 0,20 sec).[image]

To be honest I was expecting more from next.js.

I have been working on it for the last 3 days - trying diffrent next.js versions, different node.js versions etc with no success.

The only thing I have noticed: for > 1000 images using <ing> instance of next/Image gives noticable gain in performace but still for this specific case I hit the wall with 10 requests.

I have also used opentelemetry in my app, run in on localhost, when I call my page (no stress - test - just one request from my machine)  the response time is about 200-400ms.

In JaegerUI I can`t see much: static endpoint response is < 5ms, there is quite a lot of time spent on render route (app).

[image]

Am I missing something? Is there something I can tweak in node or next.js?

Mayby next.js is not designed for large pages which cannot be served as SSG?

Any suggestions will help me a lot and save my day.

Comment: Did you test this on a production build? Sounds to me as if you are trying to benchmark the dev server. We have a web shop with little over 130'000 pages that are completely SSR, and our page speed insights have never looked better.

Comment: I performed tests on production build. My conlcusion is that for relatively small pages next.js in SSR performs really good, there is a problem when the page is large, has approx 2000 elements - in that case under very small load (10 req/sec) response time is unaccceptable.

Comment: Again I find that very unlikely. Checkout [these showcases](https://nextjs.org/showcase). If the issue persists for you I'd strongly recommend you [open a issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues) on Github. StackOverflow does not seem to be the best place for your issue since there is no real question here.